# how to split string everytime it reaches 30 character

Tags: c++

how do i split the string and move it to the next line every time it reaches 30 characters? i tried search here but most of them is kind of difficult for me to understand.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main(){

    string arr;
    cout<<"Enter Sentence: ";
    getline(cin,arr);


    for(int i = 0; i<30;i++){
        cout<<i <<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int j = 0; j<arr.length(); j++){
        cout<<arr[j] <<" ";
    }   

}
```

Comment: `if (j != 0 && j % 30 == 0) cout << '\n';`

Comment: `std::cout << (j != 0 && j % 30 == 0) ? '\n' : "";`

Comment: thanks you guys, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the `substr` could help you.For example:

```
vector<string> result;
string input;
int split=0;
int size=string.size();
while(split+30<size)
{   
   result.push_back(input.substr(split,30));
   split+=30;
}
result.push_back(input.substr(split,size-split+1));
//and you can do anything you want on the list of results;
```